# Difference between in nature of usage enum and const

Tags: typescript, enums, constants

```
enum enDirection {
  UP = "UP",
  DOWN = "DOWN"
}

const coDirection = {
  UP : "UP",
  DOWN : "DOWN"
}
```

I am using **Typescript**

both the above *enDirection & coDirection* stores the same data

When should `enum` be used, and when should `const` be used ?

Comment: Ow, I thought this was about Javascript, I guess that tag should be removed.

Comment: You'd also need an `as const` behind the object literal for proper type inference. also `coDirection` holds the type of the object, you'd need `type coDirection = keyof (typeof coDirection);`. But otherwise it is up to your preference wether you use enums or not, the same applies to classes and a few other syntactic sugars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `enum` as a type for assurance but you cannot use `const` as a type

for example, using your enum type:

```js
const result: enDirection = someval; // someval must be either enDirection.UP or enDirection.DOWN
```